# Bind foreground attribute for child text of textblock element

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I've discovered that I cannot set the foreground of text that is contained within a textblock as a child (as opposed to the text being set via the Text attribute on the textblock), by simply using the Foreground attribute on the parent textblock. I've tried setting the attributes `TextElement.Foreground` and `Run.Foreground`, but neither work. Does anyone know the preferred method in this case?

Here is my code thus far:

```
    <TextBlock Foreground="{Binding ForegroundColor}">
          Sample<LineBreak/>Text
    </TextBlock>
```

edit: Here's an interesting twist: if I take the `<LineBreak/>` out, the foreground sets just fine

Comment: What type is `ForegroundColor`? For me, your XAML works if it's a `Brush` (because `TextBlock.Foreground` is `Brush`) -- but not if  `ForegroundColor` is `Color`, for obvious reasons.

Comment: The bound property, ForegroundColor, is a Brush. Perhaps it is getting overridden by a global style?

Comment: I doubt it; attributes on the element have precedence over Style setters, and I just tested it to be sure. What happens when you try setting it to a brush name string instead of the binding? e.g. `Foreground="Orange"`

Comment: Just tried setting it to Orange, and that method doesn't work either.

Comment: OK, that's seriously weird. Can you provide more context? Do I understand that it does work if you use `<TextBlock  Text="Sample Text" Foreground="{Binding ForegroundColor}">`?

Comment: Yes, that method works for me, but unfortunately it rules out using the linebreak. I'm considering using nested TextBlocks, but it seems like there has to be a better way

Comment: Right, that's not a way to fix the problem. Just thinking about diagnosing the problem (not that I got any ideas from that, sadly). If nested TextBlocks work, use them. Nothing wrong with those.

Comment: Here's an interesting twist: if I take the <LineBreak/> out, the foreground sets just fine

Comment: That's because then there are no "Sample" and "Text" Run elements created. Please see my answer for more information.

Comment: I can reproduce the issue with @mm8's answer. It makes sense: With the `LineBreak`, it must implicitly divide up the text into `Run`, `LineBreak`, `Run`. With just text, no Runs need to be created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you don't have an implicit Run style defined somewhere in your application:

```
<Style TargetType="Run">
     <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray" />
</Style>
```

This one will override the Foreground setting of the parent TextBlock.

If you do you could add an implicit Run style to the TextBlock:

```
<TextBlock>
     <TextBlock.Resources>
         <Style TargetType="Run">
             <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Orange" />
         </Style>
     </TextBlock.Resources>
    Sample<LineBreak/>Text
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Yes, that appears to be the problem. I nullified the Run style within the parent control, and the problem went away: `<Style TargetType="Run" BasedOn="{x:Null}"/>` Thanks for the help, everyone.